# Finding the matrix such that ...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $Ax = 5x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R^3$

How can I find this matrix $A |Ax = 5x  \forall x \in \mathbb R^3|$ ?

Comment: Hint: do you know something about matrix $I$ such that $Ix = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $A = 5I_3$. That is a trivial but working example.

Comment: It's the only example

Comment: There can't be another example because a linear operator is uniquely determined by its mapping of the basis elements which in that case can be taken to be (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)